# Configuring middleware to unblock Azure domain for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, azure-web-app-service, middleware

I'm developing a Rails application. I created a Web App on Azure so that the Rails app can be accessed by others for testing purposes. I got everything configured as far as Azure goes, but when I try to log on the web app, I get a blocked host error:

```
Blocked hosts: <web app name>.azurewebsites.net

To allow requests to these hosts, make sure they are valid hostnames (containing only numbers, letters, dashes and dots), then add the following to your environment configuration:

    config.hosts << "<web app name>.azurewebsites.net"
```

I went on the link to the docs, but I'm still getting the same issue. I tried adding:

```
Rails.application.config.hosts << "<web app name>.azurewebsites.net"
```

to the bottom of the config/environments/development.rb file and other variations of this but I'm still getting the same error. I'm a bit new to Rails, so if anyone has any suggestions, they would be much appreciated.

Edit: Assume I put my actually web app name and not "`<web app name>`" when running these commands.

Comment: @carmenalexander share the code of Rails application

Comment: I believe I am @dbugger , it's runs locally, just not with the Azure link

Comment: @Sampath I'm not permitted to share code for this project

Comment: How did you deploy the application. Could share the error in text

Comment: The application is not "deployed" yet. We are only running it on our local environment. The web app on Azure is the testing environment we are trying to set up. The error in my original post is what I'm getting when I follow the domain link in Azure @Sampath

Comment: Let me know if you meant something else

Comment: How to run Ruby on Rails custom [container](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/HowTo/use_ruby_with_container.md) on App               [Service](https://github.com/azure-samples/rubyrails-tasks/tree/master/)

Comment: I actually used this tutorial to set up my container @Sampath but still have the issue

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [Doc](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10) set up Ruby on Rails on Windows 10 using WSL.

To install Ruby on Rails on Windows 10 using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), follow these steps:

- **Install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)**: Open PowerShell as Administrator and run the following command:

`wsl --install -d Ubuntu`

- Open the Ubuntu terminal and run:

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get install git-core zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev software-properties-common libffi-dev`
- **Install ASDF**: Run the following commands in the Ubuntu terminal:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/excid3/asdf.git ~/.asdf
echo '. "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo '. "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'legacy_version_file = yes' >> ~/.asdfrc
echo 'export EDITOR="code --wait"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
```

- **Install Ruby and Node.js**: Install ASDF plugins for Ruby and Node.js by running:

`asdf plugin add ruby`
`asdf plugin add nodejs`

```
Then install the desired versions of Ruby and Node.js:
```

```
asdf install ruby 3.3.0
asdf global ruby 3.3.0
gem update --system
asdf install nodejs 20.11.0
asdf global nodejs 20.11.0
npm install -g yarn
```

- Run the following commands in the Ubuntu terminal, replacing "your name" and "your@email.com" with your GitHub username and email:

  asdf install ruby 3.3.0
  asdf global ruby 3.3.0
  gem update --system
  asdf install nodejs 20.11.0
  asdf global nodejs 20.11.0
  npm install -g yarn

  Add the SSH key to your GitHub account.
- Install Rails by running:

  `gem install rails -v 7.1.3`
- Install PostgreSQL and start the service:

`sudo apt install postgresql libpq-dev`

`sudo service postgresql start`

Then create a user with permission to create databases:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser <your_username> -s
sudo -u postgres psql
postgres=# \password <your_username>
```

- If you setup MySQL or Postgres with a username/password, modify the  # config/database.yml file to contain the username/password that you specified

8. **Create a new Rails application**: Navigate to your desired directory and run:

`rails new weblog`

`cd weblog`

`rails server`

(or)

```
`rails new myapp -d postgresql
cd myapp
rake db:create
rails server`
```

- Ruby on Rails on Azure App Service  with [Linux](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ruby-on-rails-on-azure-app-service-web-sites-with-linux-and-ubuntu-on-windows-10)

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

- For more details follow this [DOC](https://mohamedradwan.com/2019/12/17/ruby-on-rails-and-postgres-on-azure-end-to-end-tutorial-developing-and-deploying-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres-on-the-cloud/) Ruby on Rails and Postgres on Azure End To End  Developing and Deploying Ruby.